# BootstrapValidator Not Validating Visible Field After Being Hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form that hides some input fields, those hidden fields are made visible depending on a specific selection. However, BootstrapValidator will not validate them when I want them to be validated.

I've put together a JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/FLz6B/1/

I am aware that in order for BootstrapValidator to validate hidden fields, you need to define the "excluded" element, like this;

```
$('#loginform').bootstrapValidator({
    excluded: [":disabled"]
});
```

But if I use that on my page, it will try to validate the hidden fields when they may not be needed for validation.

I've also looked at the BootstrapValidator toggle example which seems to replicate what I am trying to acheive, but I haven't been able to get that to work. (http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/toggle/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue myself.

Using the same initial call:

```
// Exclude disabled fields from validation
$('#loginform').bootstrapValidator({
    excluded: [":disabled"]
});
```

I then created a selector which forced the user to make a selection:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Type</option>
  <option value="type1">Type #1</option>
  <option value="type2">Type #2</option>
</select>
```

Below that, I have some hidden fields which depend on which type is selected.

```
<!-- display and validate always -->
<div id="type1fields">
  <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1">
</div>

<!-- display and validate only if "type2" is selected -->
<div id="type2fields" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="field2" id="field2">
</div>
```

Then I used jQuery to set/unset the fields to disabled as needed:

```
$("#type").on("change", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

  if(val === "type1") {
    $("#type2fields").fadeOut(); // fade out in case user previously selected it
    $("#field2").attr("disabled", true); // set field to disabled
  }

  if(val === "type2") {
    $("#type2fields").fadeIn();
    $("#field2").attr("disabled", false); // remove the disabled element in case user previously selected it
  }

});
```